# What is the way to select all sub elements of a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, checkbox

I have several forms, some of which are dynamically added to my page. They all share the same class, but have no unique id. For each form, when the user hits the submit button, I need to iterate over the checkboxes of the corresponding form and perform some logic. I am using jquery v2.1.1. Currently, what I have selects all the checkboxes of all the forms.

Here is my javascript code using jquery.

```
$document.on("submit","form.myclazz", function() {
 $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
  console.log(this.name + " " + $(this).is(":checked"));
 });
});
```

Again, I only want to select the checkboxes of the form that was submitted. I also tried the following selector syntax, which didn't work.

```
$("> input[type=checkbox]").each(function() { ... });
```

The forms are appended to a div and the html looks like the following:

```
<div id="myforms">
 <form class="myclazz"> ... <input type="checkbox" name="x">X ... <input type="submit"> </form>
 <form class="myclazz"> ... <input type="checkbox" name="y">Y ... <input type="submit"> </form>
</div>
```

Comment: And by "sub elements" you mean all the children, right? Not the `<sub>` elements in the form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an instance of `this` to your selector to get the children of that form:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]", this).each(function() {
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

```
jQuery(".myclazz input[type=submit][clicked=true]").parents("form:first")
```

should give you the form inside on("submit")

if you don't use input change input[type=submit][clicked=true] to whatever you use to submit the form if it's inside the form tag ex. button[type=submit]